Plotting heatmap with gridlines in matplotlib misses gridlines
I am trying to plot a heatmap with gridlines. This is my code (adapted from this post):
# Plot a heatmap with gridlines

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from functional import seq

arr = np.random.randn(3, 20)

plt.tight_layout()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.imshow(arr, cmap='viridis')

xr = ax.get_xlim()
yr = ax.get_ylim()
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(max(xr))-0.5, minor=True)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(max(yr))-0.5, minor=True)
ax.grid(which='minor', snap=False, color='k', linestyle='-', linewidth=1)
ax.tick_params(which='major', bottom=False, left=False)
ax.tick_params(which='minor', bottom=False, left=False)
ax.set_xticklabels([])
ax.set_yticklabels([])
for spine in ax.spines.values():
    spine.set_visible(False)


plt.show()

I get the following plot (cropped to content):

There are no vertical grid lines after the 3rd, 8th, and third to last columns. As this script uses minor ticks to plot grid lines, I also thought to print the xticks and make the same plot without hiding the labels:
print('xticks:', np.arange(max(xr))-0.5)

xticks: [-0.5  0.5  1.5  2.5  3.5  4.5  5.5  6.5  7.5  8.5  9.5 10.5 11.5 12.5
 13.5 14.5 15.5 16.5 17.5 18.5]


which show that all the necessary ticks are there. What could be the issue here?

I have no idea why this happens. Using the major grid instead fixes this issue:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arr = np.random.randn(3, 20)

plt.tight_layout()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.imshow(arr, cmap='viridis')

xr = ax.get_xlim()
yr = ax.get_ylim()
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(max(xr))-0.5, minor=False)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(max(yr))-0.5, minor=False)

ax.grid(which='major', snap=False, color='k', linestyle='-', linewidth=1)

ax.tick_params(which='major', bottom=False, left=False)
ax.tick_params(which='minor', bottom=False, left=False)

plt.show()


Ah, works perfectly. Thank you!

Actually it will work with minor ticks also, if you set the major ticks and not only the minor ticks.

Actually it's a bit tricky but the issue is that in your code you only set the minor ticks. As you didn't set the major ticks, matplotlib did it for you.
If you print the location of the ticks with print(ax.get_xticks()) you will get:
[-2.5  0.   2.5  5.   7.5 10.  12.5 15.  17.5 20. ]

If you look at your plot, you will notice that the minor grids are absent for each of the location where there are major ticks  i.e. at x = 2.5, 7.5, 12.5 and 17.5. And if we think about it, it make sense. The main ticks are the major ticks (if we don't define them, matplotlib will do for us) and then BETWEEN the major ticks there are minor ticks.
So to have a nice grid, just add the following in your code before the setting of the minor ticks:
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(max(xr)), minor=False)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(max(yr)), minor=False)



Ah, that makes sense! Thank you!

thanks for the explanation!

@DavidK. You are welcome, too bad that my answer was not accepted ;-)
